# Submissions from page opened using apex.navigation.redirect function are not shown in Debug

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I have modal page that called using `apex.navigation.redirect(url)` function in the caller page. The modal page opened. Now in the modal page submittion using this code when a button clicked:

```
apex.page.submit({
    request: "CREATE",
    reloadOnSubmit: "A",
    validate: true,
});
```

The problem is this submission is or any calling ajax process in the modal page is not shown in Debug page. Generally in my sitaution, any request from the modal page is not shown in Debug. why? are there any option must be setted when call the modal page?

I expect all requests for the page called using  `apex.navigation.redirect(url)` javascript function shown in the debug as what happened in the normal behavior when page called without using that function.

NOTE: When any page including model pages opened using redirect and the the target is *page in this application* within apex then the first debug message shown has Path Info called show. this message was not shown in my situation.

Comment: A model page (aka popup) comes with its own debug window.  In Chrome DevTools, you can activate the checkbox "Settings > Preferences > Global > Auto-open DevTools for popups".

Comment: actaully I want to track the results of process that fired after page submitted. I think there is a confusion, I mean the apex server debug not the broswer.

Comment: what is the value of the "debug" argument in the url that you're calling in the redirect call ? It sounds like that is not set. For debugging purposes you might want to hardcode it to 'YES'.